# Call body of all traits inherited

Tags: scala

Say I have the below:

```
type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
trait Functionality {
    /**
     * A set containing all Receive functions 
     */
    var allReceives: Set[Receive] = Set[Receive]() 
}
```

Now other trait's can extend `Functionality` and do awesome stuff. Example:

```
trait LoadBalancer extends Functionality{
  def body:Receive = {
     case ...
  }
  allReceives += body
}
```

And ultimately my class:

```
class Main with LoadBalancer with SecurityFunctionality 
                      with OtherFunctionality with Functionality{

    def receive =  {
      case x if allReceives.foldLeft(false) { (z, f) => if (f isDefinedAt x) { f(x); true } else z } == true => ()
    }

    def body: Receive = {
    }
    allReceives += body
}
```

**Question**: What I wish to do is, in `Main` I need to call `body` function of all the traits that I have inherited. This way my code can be loosely coupled and I can add/remove functionality at a go.

The above works, but I do not like it as the compiler cannot guarantee that any trait that extends `Functionality` should add its `body` to `allReceives`.

I cannot declare `def body:Receive` in `Functionality` as then my implementation in `Main` will override `body` implementations of other traits. I am sure there should be a smarter way!

Comment: I think composition may be cleaner and safer solution here than stackable traits.

Comment: Could not the Template method pattern help here? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) The other option might be using macro annotations.

Comment: @ghik I doubt how it will be cleaner as again then I will have to explicitly create instances of all the traits and then call them. Probably you can tell more on it.

Comment: @GáborBakos Nope. In that pattern you only call one trait then but here I need to call all of the. And not macros, it would be complicating the stuff unnecessarily.

Comment: @Jatin Sorry, I was thinking calling the super implementations of other traits there, but probably that do not work. Thanks.

Comment: @Jatin by "cleaner and safer" I meant not the solution with most concise syntax but the one that is more easily maintainable, easy to change and less error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, composition really might be a better option here. This is a simpler solution, without any funny "abstract override"s:

```
object Main {
  type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]

  trait Receiver {
    def receive: Receive 
  }

  class LoadBalancer extends Receiver {
    override def receive: Receive = {  
      case "one" => println("LoadBalancer received one")
    }
  }

  class OtherFunctionality extends Receiver {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case "two" => println("OtherFunctionality received two")
    }  
  }

  class MainFunctionality extends Receiver {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case "three" => println("MainFunctionality received three")
    }   
  }

  class CompositeReceiver(receivers: List[Receiver]) extends Receiver {
    override def receive: Receive = { 
      case msg => 
        receivers.find(_.receive.isDefinedAt(msg)) map (_.receive(msg))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val main = new CompositeReceiver(List(new OtherFunctionality, new LoadBalancer, new MainFunctionality))

    main.receive("one")
    main.receive("two")
    main.receive("three")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not really answer your question, but here is a solution using the [stackable traits pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html). Alas you still need to call super.receive as the last case in each trait, but I could not find a way around that yet.

```
object Main {
  type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]

  trait Receiver {
    def receive: Receive 
  }

  trait LoadBalancer extends Receiver {
    abstract override def receive: Receive = {  
      case "one" => println("LoadBalancer received one")
      case msg => super.receive(msg)
    }
  }

  trait OtherFunctionality extends Receiver {
    abstract override def receive: Receive = {
        case "two" => println("OtherFunctionality received two")
        case msg => super.receive(msg)
    }  
  }

  class Main extends Receiver {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case "three" => println("Main received three")
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val main = new Main with OtherFunctionality with LoadBalancer

    main.receive("one")
    main.receive("two")
    main.receive("three")
  }
}
```

Comment: This indeed is a good solution. I had given a thought to it earlier (inspired from Jonas Boner blog on AOP in scala) but still it has quite some boiler plate code. In many such cases there cannot be  a signle right answer and I guess I might go ahead with this one.